# How to make your OWN console like windows command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pycharm, pyqt5

As you have seen in PyCharm,
the state of the art console, I am trying to make one
please tell me how to do it.

I know that **subprocess** module is quite handy for this case.

I have a exe file called **add.exe**
The code in **Python 3x** for that **add.exe** file will be,

```
a = input('Enter 1st Number')
b = input('Enter 2nd Number')
print('a + b =', a + b)
```

Now when i use subprocess to Run this in Background and fetch me the output and then supply input i get just one big black Empty Console Screen.
[image: My Console Window]
Oh! This looks Ugly.

I just want to fetch my Output and get prompt when the program demands input but
**Without Opening an Console**
My code So far is this,

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['add.exe'],
          stdout=PIPE,
          stdin=PIPE,
          )
p.stdin.write(b'4')
p.stdin.write(b'6')
print(p.stdout.read())
```

Then I get that stupid Console
And When I close that console I get the output on my IDLE,

**b'Enter 1st Number: '**

What should I do!!
Some body please help.

Answer (score 2):

console.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import check_output, PIPE

commands = ['add.exe', 'sub.exe', 'print', 'exit', 'quit']

# Only commands with a set number of arguments
num_cmd_args = {
    'add.exe': 2,
    'sub.exe': 2
}

# Command help messages
cmd_helps = {
    'add.exe': 'Adds 2 numbers together. Returns num1 + num2',
    'sub.exe': 'Subtracts 2 numbers. Returns num1 - num2',
    'print': 'Prints all arguments passed'
}

while True:
    user_in = input('$ ').split()
    cmd = user_in[0]
    args = user_in[1:]
    # Default to '*' if not cmd not found in num_cmd_args
    n_args_needed = num_cmd_args.get(cmd, '*')

    # Check cmd
    if cmd not in commands:
        print('command not found:', cmd)
        continue
    elif cmd in ('exit', 'quit'):
        break

    # To make this much better, you're probably going to want to
    #  do some type checking to make sure that the user entered
    #  numbers for commands like add.exe and sub.exe. I suggest
    #  also looking at word splitting and maybe escaping special
    #  characters like \x07b or \u252c.

    # Check cmd's args
    if n_args_needed != len(args):
        print(cmd_helps[cmd])
    elif n_args_needed in ('*', num_cmd_args[cmd]):
        out = check_output(['./'+cmd, *args])
        print(out.decode(), end='')
```

---

And these are my c++ files:

add.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << atoi(argv[1]) + atoi(argv[2]) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

sub.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << atoi(argv[1]) - atoi(argv[2]) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

print.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bro i get it but as you can see I'm trying to create another console similar to pycharm so the executable file might contain different kinds of input or output messages so can you please modify the program so that it can scrap the console message and prompt me for input if required and then again display the resulting output.

Comment: @Nikhil That's the thing, unless a program has a help message option (for example, `add.exe /?`), there is no way to know what kind of input a program requires. Even if it does, you would have to do some fairly complex parsing to understand what kind of input the help message tells you the program requires. For what you want, you will have to code the logic to be able to handle the inputs for each program a user could try to run.

Comment: What if I put this code inside while loop `p.stdout.read(1)`
If I even do this then there is one problem once the cursor hits the end character in the console then the program runs forever unless I provide an input but the problem is it hangs and then there is no way to provide any kind of input by using this code `print('some input', file=p.stdin)`
Please help...

Comment: And when I said my code will hang I meant the code will wait unless and until the program exits or I provide all the input required,
Which means it is waiting for EOF.

Comment: @Nikhil The only way I can get the executable to read any kind of input is by passing it in the `Popen` call like I have in my example. If you can get it to work using `p.stdin` or `print(..., file=p.stdin)` that's awesome, but you still have to know what kind of input the program requires and code that logic into your term emulator emulator.

Comment: Assume that my program will always require console input and output.
Just like in command prompt.

Comment: Is there any way to know how many letters are present on the console at any particular moment if there is then I think I can use a for loop and print(p.stdout.read(1))
Because if I go the other way then my program well step into an infinite loop and wait for end of file.

Comment: @Nikhil Without making things too complicated, you can keep track of how many arguments each command takes and make sure the user inputs that many arguments. I can show you an example of that.

Comment: @Nikhil What do you mean by letters present on the console? The number of characters already printed out? The number of characters a user inputs?

Comment: Letter present in the console means length of the string present at a moment on a console.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this is not what I need,
In command prompt u must have seen when u type the executable name(Console App) it displays the statements until it hits the EOF or until it hits the input().

I want to know how do they do it if you have any other solutions to do the same please suggest!!

Comment: @Nikhil Are you talking about the python console?

Comment: Yeah u can say that as py console == cmd console

Comment: Just to double check, you're talking about the console with a prompt that looks like this: `>>> `, correct?

Comment: That is it , Yeah